# Multi toggle switch using in Laravel is getting just first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

[image]

```
//IN PAGE
    
        @foreach ($permissionlist as $pl)
<label class="switch">
                                                       
 @php if(true===$pl->roleisactive){ @endphp
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" checked> 
@php }else{ @endphp
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch">                                                 
 @php } @endphp
  <span class="slider round"></span>  </label>          

<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="{{$pl->permissionid}}">
        @endforeach

//IN SCRİPT

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name=onoffswitch]').click(function(){
        $id=$(this).attr('id');
        $status = $(this).val();
        var id= $('#id').val();   
        alert(id);  //is returning just 2
    });
</script>
```

I can write just first id element in script. But I want to get last or others data with script. How can i do that ?

Comment: I think you should probably define id's unique `id='id-<?=$loop->iteration ?>'`

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Yeah but How can i call this in js ?

Comment: The elements ID should be unique for the document. Why do you use $ for variables in javascript?

Comment: @CansuKoç first some questions, i think you are overcomplicating it . Is the input needed? you can give the checkbox a value (the id)

Comment: Also instead of using `@php @endphp` you can use `@if() ...  @else  ... @endif` (you should take a look at the docs for Blade templates)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@foreach ($permissionlist as $pl)
<label class="switch">
                                                       
 @php if(true===$pl->roleisactive){ @endphp
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch"  checked> 
@php }else{ @endphp
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch">                                                 
 @php } @endphp
  <span class="slider round"></span>  </label>          

<input type="text" name="id" id="id-{{$pl->permissionid}}" data-switch="{{$pl->permissionid}}" value="{{$pl->permissionid}}">
        @endforeach

//IN SCRİPT

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name=onoffswitch]').click(function(){
        var id=$(this).data('switch');
        console.log('id',id);
        var value= $('#id-'+id).val();   
        alert(value);  
    });
</script>
```